# Efficient way of searching an index with 2 criterias on a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to find the index of a multidimensional array given two values, one of the values is repeated several times since it is a list of states and cities, here's an example

```
array(
        99773000 => array('State' => 'ANTIOQUIA', 'City' => 'CUMARIBO'),
        99624000 => array('State' => 'ANTIOQUIA', 'City' => 'SANTA ROSALIA'),
        99524000 => array('State' => 'VICHADA', 'City' => 'LA PRIMAVERA'),
        99001000 => array('State' => 'VICHADA', 'City' => 'PUERTO CARREÑO'),
        .....
        xxxxxxxx => array('State') => etc......
);
```

Now, I receive in the function a state and a city and I need to return the index, this is how Im doing it right now:

```
        foreach ( $array as $index => $state_and_city ) {

            $current_state = $state_and_city['State'];

            $current_city = $state_and_city['City'];

            if( $current_state == $state  && $current_city == $city) {
                return $index;
            }
        }

        return '';
```

I would like to know if there's a more efficient approach of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Here you just need to get the keys from the inner array and that can be achieved by `array_search` function.

```
 foreach ($array as $index => $state_and_city ) {

            $current_state = $state_and_city['State'];

            $current_city = $state_and_city['City'];

           $state_key = array_search($current_state,$index);
           $city_key = array_search($current_city,$index);


            if($state_key == $state  && $city_key == $city) {
                return $index;
            }
        }

        return '';
```

Comment: alright I would like to know why it is faster than the other method... I mean a technical reason.

Comment: Because in the method mentioned initially one added loop causes a time difference for it self to be executed.

Comment: And now its all in one loop so it is gonna make things execute fast.

Comment: Yeah but it's basically the same I did already, the difference is that you're using this `array_search` extra method, which I think adds extra steps to what I had already... So that's why Im asking.

Comment: No by your way  you will only get the values of the desired key but in by using my code you will get the keys from the desired array and can use them for further operations comparing these both of our codes there so role of time but it;s all about the rightness.

Comment: Your code wouldn't had gave you desired answer you can check it.

Comment: Yes It would indeed I need the value of the key, not the position in the array if that's what you mean... Unfortunately, your solution is not more optimal, I tested it and it takes more execution time...